# Download video with yt-dlp using format id

Tags: python, yt-dlp

How can I download a specific format without using options like "best video", using the format ID... example: 139, see the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MlOf.jpg)

```
❯ yt-dlp --list-formats https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc
[youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc 
[youtube] BaW_jenozKc: Downloading webpage 
[youtube] BaW_jenozKc: Downloading android player API JSON 
[info] Available formats for BaW_jenozKc: 
ID  EXT  RESOLUTION FPS CH │   FILESIZE   TBR PROTO │ VCODEC        VBR ACODEC      ABR ASR MORE INFO
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
139 m4a  audio only      2 │   58.59KiB   48k https │ audio only        mp4a.40.5   48k 22k low, m4a_dash     
249 webm audio only      2 │   58.17KiB   48k https │ audio only        opus        48k 48k low, webm_dash    
250 webm audio only      2 │   76.07KiB   63k https │ audio only        opus        63k 48k low, webm_dash    
140 m4a  audio only      2 │  154.06KiB  128k https │ audio only        mp4a.40.2  128k 44k medium, m4a_dash  
251 webm audio only      2 │  138.96KiB  116k https │ audio only        opus       116k 48k medium, webm_dash 
17  3gp  176x144     12  1 │   55.79KiB   45k https │ mp4v.20.3     45k mp4a.40.2    0k 22k 144p
160 mp4  256x144     15    │  135.08KiB  113k https │ avc1.4d400c  113k video only          144p, mp4_dash    
278 webm 256x144     30    │   52.22KiB   44k https │ vp9           44k video only          144p, webm_dash   
133 mp4  426x240     30    │  294.27KiB  246k https │ avc1.4d4015  246k video only          240p, mp4_dash    
242 webm 426x240     30    │   33.27KiB   28k https │ vp9           28k video only          240p, webm_dash   
134 mp4  640x360     30    │  349.59KiB  292k https │ avc1.4d401e  292k video only          360p, mp4_dash    
18  mp4  640x360     30  2 │ ~525.60KiB  420k https │ avc1.42001E  420k mp4a.40.2    0k 44k 360p
243 webm 640x360     30    │   75.55KiB   63k https │ vp9           63k video only          360p, webm_dash   
135 mp4  854x480     30    │  849.41KiB  710k https │ avc1.4d401f  710k video only          480p, mp4_dash    
244 webm 854x480     30    │  165.49KiB  138k https │ vp9          138k video only          480p, webm_dash   
22  mp4  1280x720    30  2 │ ~  1.82MiB 1493k https │ avc1.64001F 1493k mp4a.40.2    0k 44k 720p
136 mp4  1280x720    30    │    1.60MiB 1366k https │ avc1.4d401f 1366k video only          720p, mp4_dash    
247 webm 1280x720    30    │  504.68KiB  420k https │ vp9          420k video only          720p, webm_dash   
137 mp4  1920x1080   30    │    2.11MiB 1803k https │ avc1.640028 1803k video only          1080p, mp4_dash   
248 webm 1920x1080   30    │  965.31KiB  804k https │ vp9          804k video only          1080p, webm_dash
```

I tried using the format url, but it didn't work

Comment: do you mean **yt-dlp -f 139 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc** . yt-dlp --help gives all options

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
yt-dlp -f <format_id> <url>
```

Answer (score 1):

When ID in output of **yt-dlp --list-formats**  contains other chars other than numbers, make sure to put the ID **in quotes** like **-f 'id-abc_01-a'**.

If you want a video *and* audio in one file, use **+** like **-f 'abc_01+audio_02'** and make sure to use **--merge-output-format**  to choose your preferred container format like **mp4** (as of 2024-03 currently possible formats: avi, flv, mkv, mov, mp4, webm).

Example:

```
yt-dlp -f 'abc_01+audio_02' --merge-output-format mp4 <video-url>
```